# TextView android is not displayed in the view

Tags: android, textview

I have a problem with an item in the view of my Activity. I have the following item:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/numero_asiento_alert"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/msg_numero_alert"
                android:textColor="@color/result_minor_text"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
                android:paddingRight="4dip"
                android:textSize="22sp"/>
```

In one of the functions of my Activity I have the following code:

```
if(!inscripcion.getAsiento().equals("") && !inscripcion.getAsiento().equals("null")){
    asientoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numero_asiento_alert);
    asientoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    asientoTextView.setText("Asiento: "+inscripcion.getAsiento());
    System.out.println("Asiento "+asientoTextView.toString()+" "+asientoTextView.getText());
}else{
    asientoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numero_asiento_alert);
    asientoTextView.setText("");
}
```

Output :

```
08-04 10:50:44.537: I/System.out(6750): Asiento android.widget.TextView{418e3140 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090050 app:id/numero_asiento_alert} Asiento: Fila B - Asiento 4
```

I thought the value was not getting is why I printed that contained my element TextView and effectively if it has the values seteo but the view is not shown, being the'm visibility by setting properly. It happens with this and 2 more elements, whereas in others there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

```
if(!inscripcion.getAsiento().equals("") && !inscripcion.getAsiento().equals("null")){
```

to:

```
if (inscripcion.getAsiento() != null) if (!inscripcion.getAsiento().isEmpty() && !inscripcion.getAsiento().equals("")) {
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but it does not solve my problem as I found the error, you helped me a lot to improve my syntax!

The error is that after displaying the values, cleaned all the elements.